# Recursive Call and Function Definition

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to implement what should be a simple coding interview-like question. However, I'm having difficulty making the recursive call:

```
(function () {
if(typeof Algorithms === "undefined") {
  window.Algorithms = {};
}

// Write a method, digital_root(num).
// It should sum the digits of a positive integer.
// If it is greater than or equal to 10, sum the digits of the resulting number.
// Keep repeating until there is only one digit in the result, called the "digital root".
// Do not use string conversion within your method.
Algorithms.digitalRoot = function (number) {
    if (number < 10) {
        return number;
    }

    var sum = 0;
    while(number != 0) {
        sum += number % 10;
        number = Math.floor(number/10);
    }
    this.digitalRoot(sum);
};
```

The spec looks like so:

```
 it("65,536 should return 7", function() {
    expect(Algorithms.digitalRoot(65536)).toBe(7);
  });

  it("1,853 should return 8", function() {
    expect(Algorithms.digitalRoot(1853)).toBe(8);
  });
```

I thought what happened was: `Algorithms` is an object that has `digitalRoot` as a property (specifically a function). Thus, when `Algorithms.digitalRoot(number_here)` is called, the `this` should refer to `Algorithms`. Therefore, I wrote the recursive call like `this.digitalRoot(sum)`. Could someone please correct my incorrect thinking?

The error reads as below:

> digitalRoot 65,536 should return 7. Expected undefined to be 7. Error:
>   Expected undefined to be 7.
>       at new jasmine.ExpectationResult (file:///C:/Users/Documents/GitHub/practice-thy-algorithms/Javascript/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js:114:32)
>       at null.toBe (file:///C:/Users/Documents/GitHub/practice-thy-algorithms/Javascript/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js:1235:29)
>       at null. (file:///C:/Users/Documents/GitHub/practice-thy-algorithms/Javascript/spec/algorithms_spec.js:3:43)
>       at jasmine.Block.execute (file:///C:/Users/Documents/GitHub/practice-thy-algorithms/Javascript/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js:1064:17)
>       at jasmine.Queue.next_ (file:///C:/Users/Documents/GitHub/practice-thy-algorithms/Javascript/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js:2096:31)
>       at jasmine.Queue.start (file:///C:/Users/Documents/GitHub/practice-thy-algorithms/Javascript/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js:2049:8)
>       at jasmine.Spec.execute (file:///C:/Users/Documents/GitHub/practice-thy-algorithms/Javascript/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js:2376:14)
>       at jasmine.Queue.next_ (file:///C:/Users/Documents/GitHub/practice-thy-algorithms/Javascript/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js:2096:31)
>       at jasmine.Queue.start (file:///C:/Users/Documents/GitHub/practice-thy-algorithms/Javascript/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js:2049:8)
>       at jasmine.Suite.execute (file:///C:/Users/Documents/GitHub/practice-thy-algorithms/Javascript/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js:2521:14)

Comment: What makes you think your code is wrong?

Comment: @FelixKling Whoops, just edited to include the error from testing.

Comment: At the very least, change `this.digitalRoot(sum);` to `return this.digitalRoot(sum);` since you are never returning a value from your first call to `digitalRoot()` unless the starting number < 10.

Comment: @jfriend00, that was it. I was stuck in Ruby mode and forgot to return..garr.

Comment: Be careful with `this.digitalRoot(sum);`. You're assuming *this* will resolve to the global object, but in strict mode, it will be undefined.

Comment: @RobG - they are calling it initially as `Algorithms.digitalRoot()` so `this` will be the `Algorithms` object, even in strict mode.

Comment: Ah yes, got lost in the IIFE. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't return anything from your function unless `number < 10`. That is why you are getting `undefined` instead of `7`. Your expectation about `this` was correct.

Return the value `this.digitalRoot(sum);`:

```
        ...

        number = Math.floor(number/10);
    }

    return this.digitalRoot(sum);
};
```